# SQL Server identity num starts from a number randomly instead of 1

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table which has an id column for  auto increment num for each row
but my Id num is starts from a random number.

Here is my table; my column is called `ID` which I want to count for each row from 1 to infinity, but it doesn't start from 1, it starts at a random number.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. (I can't read what is in that image).

Comment: You need to show the DDL for your table definition. But if you define it as `int identity (1,1)` it will most definitely start at 1, but if you delete record then it doesn't reset.

Comment: If you treat identity as an *opaque identifier* that happens to be stored in a numeric column, all will be well. If you care about the *actual numeric values assigned*, it's almost certainly the *wrong tool*.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems ok, the numbers are increasing and if there is a space between them you may have deleted items. Please test this code to reset the identity of the table.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('Players', RESEED, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks guys for helping I really appreciate it I turned the ( identity num) on  but did not mark the Id column as  Key